# MFC: Why does this heap corruption happen? (array_s.cpp / afxcoll.inl)

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

#### Crashing Code

The following code makes my program crash (program exits) by heap corruption when the third line (the 'delete' command) is called:

```
1: CStringArray* pStringArray = new CStringArray();
2: ClassInDll::addToStringArray(_T("asdf"), *pStringArray);
3: delete pStringArray;
```

with

```
1: ClassInDll::addToStringArray(CString s, CStringArray& sa){
2:  sa.Add(s);
3: }
```

addToStringArray() is static

- Be aware that this is not actually my code, but simply the minimum with which I can reproduce the error. It is reproducible with CArray<CString> as well.
- I verified, that the heap corruption does indeed **not** happen **before** that code line via
  `gflags /p /enable MyExe.exe /full`

StackTrace:

[image: StackTrace]

---

#### What seems to be the problem

|  |  | Dll dependency | MFC source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CStringArray creation | MyExe.exe > MFC | ...\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\array_s.cpp |
| 2 | Internal array allocation | MyExe.exe > MyDll.dll > MFC | ...\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxcoll.inl |
| 3 | Deletion | MyExe.exe > MFC | ...\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\array_s.cpp |

The fact that the internal array is not deleted the same way it was created is probably the error. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

---

#### Project Settings

I made sure that the same MFC settings are used in MyExe.exe as well as MyDll.dll, i.e.:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Use of MFC | Use MFC in a Shared DLL |
| Use of ATL | Not using ATL |
| Character Set | Use Unicode Character Set |

I test in debug mode, so there is no optimization.

---

#### Question

MyDll.dll is not the only dll that is loaded, and there is too much going on with project dependencies (to third party dlls etc), so I cannot make all this part of my question.

So my questions boil down to:

- Is my assumption correct that array_s.cpp and afxcoll.inl are not compatible with one another?
- What makes one piece of code call array_s.cpp, and the other call afxcoll.inl?
- What else could be the problem?

I have tried turning it off and on again ;)

Thank you in advance!

---

#### Update

PaulMcKenzie pointed out that this is the case if I build against different CRTs which was the case. One was "Multithreaded Debug DLL", the other was "Multithreaded DLL". Still, the problem persists, after making both equal. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries?view=msvc-160) states that if using VS 2015 and above with Windows 10 and having project settings so that the same runtime library is used, the same CRT library is used at runtime (and therefore should use the same heap, right?).

I've made sure, that every entry within "Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation" is exactly the same in the exe and dll.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is inside the DLL and the `addToStringArray` function? Perhaps the problem is somewhere else completely? Heap corruptions typically happens when you write out of bounds of allocated memory, which can happen *anywhere* in your program, but manifest at a much later point in time (and code location). I suggest you try to create a proper [mcve] that you can run and debug, and perhaps find some static analyzer tool and run-time heap memory debugger tool to help you figure this out.

Comment: You use `new` to create an object, and then you delete it.  So what is `ClassInDll` holding when step 3) is completed?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for answering. The addToStringArray function works fine. I've added its code to the question. As I've written, I've (hopefully) made sure, that the heap corruption did not occur before the piece of code in question by using gflags.

Comment: [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The deletion does not go through. The crash happens **while** deleting the object. (When the internal array is deleted.)

Comment: @Duderino Your code shows that you are passing a `CStringArray` *object* (`*pStringArray`), not a pointer, but your `addToStringArray` takes a pointer as the second argument.   What makes sense would be `ClassInDll::addToStringArray(_T("asdf"), pStringArray);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My bad. Copy/Paste error. Corrected it. So that's not the problem

Comment: @Duderino *I made sure that the same MFC settings are used in MyExe.exe as well as MyDll.dll, i.e.:* -- Doesn't really mean anything unless the actual CRT uses the multithread DLL runtime.  The reason is that you are creating an object that relies on the heap in some way, and the `ClassInDll` may be using a different heap, causing the errors.

Comment: @IInspectable That seems to be the exact problem. I don't know, though, why the CRTs are different. How do I change, what  CRT is used?

Comment: @Duderino -- If you're using Visual Studio: `Project settings->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie One is Multi-threaded DLL, one is Multi-threaded **debug** Dll. I changed it to be the same, but unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: The issue isn't just about the CRT. It's *any* library you use. Once you start mixing different versions (which is what causes different copies to exist), things start falling apart. C++ has no good answer to that problem. COM does.

Comment: @IInspectable So even if those other libraries don't have anything to do with the code in question, they might cause a problem? The only libraries that are uses for that piece of code are my exe, my dll and MFC libraries.

Comment: Your executable has dependencies, your DLL has dependencies, and MFC has dependencies. Just because you don't see those dependencies in your code does not make them not *"have anything to do with the code in question"*. Though, really, if you want to get to the bottom of this, you should at least explain what a *"crash"* means to you. If the system shuts down your process due to an unhandled exception make sure to show the call stack at the point the exception is thrown.

Comment: Quite likely, the DLL you linked against is compiled as a Release configuration, which upsets the executable, that's using a a debug heap implementation when it tries to delete the object. Hard to track down without a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable Making a minimal reproducible example would have taken me a day minimum, because the project is relatively complex. I was merely asking on SO to get hints in the right direction, which thankfully you provided me. It was exaclty what you expected previously. It turned out that both msvcr100.dll and msvcr100d.dll were being loaded. I could now track it down to the bad piece of code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you can, avoid to use `CStringArray` and use `std::vector<CString>` instead. In the past  it was not true, but nowadays there is absolutely no advantage to use the old CRT collection classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that release **and** debug dlls were both being loaded (because of another dll):

- msvcr100.dll
- msvcr100d.dll
- msvcp100.dll
- msvcp100d.dll

The "modules" window sure does help, if you only know that you should look there.

Thanks to PaulMcKenzie and IInspectable for leading me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Passing MFC objects (even *via* pointers) between modules (EXEs and DLLs, or different DLLs) is a *very* tricky business. If you're simply *using* classes in the DLL, then you should (at the very least) be using the `AFX_MANAGE_STATE` macro (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/regular-dlls-dynamically-linked-to-mfc?view=msvc-160)) in the DLL.

However, if your DLL is *defining its own* MFC-derived classes (your `ClassInDll` seems to be such), it should really be built as an [MFC Extension DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/extension-dlls?view=msvc-160).

The whole process of building extension DLLs (and even using the 'regular' MFC DLLs) is rather too broad for me to provide any usable source code for you here. But, from the second link above, the following section is likely relevant to the problem(s) you are seeing (bold italics are mine):

> #### Memory Management
>
> MFCx0.dll and all MFC extension DLLs loaded into a client
> application's address space ***use the same memory allocator***, resource
> loading, and other MFC global states as if they were in the same
> application. This is significant because the non-MFC DLL libraries and
> the regular MFC DLLs do the exact opposite ***and have each DLL
> allocating out of its own memory pool***.
>
> If an MFC extension DLL allocates memory, that memory can freely
> intermix with any other application-allocated object. Also, if an
> application that dynamically links to MFC fails, the protection of the
> operating system maintains the integrity of any other MFC application
> sharing the DLL.
>
> Similarly other global MFC states, like the current executable file to
> load resources from, are also shared between the client application
> and all MFC extension DLLs as well as MFCx0.dll itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! It turned out to be msvc*dlls being loaded both in their debug and release variants.

Comment: @Duderino Glad you resolved your issue. However, be aware that other MFC-related issues (memory, resources, state flags, etc.) should also be 'synchronized' between modules. Using Extension DLLs is one way (probably the best way) to achieve this. Bypassing such issues may well lead to more problems down the road, especially if you do a lot of class-passing between modules.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm definately going to read more about that.